# What is correct "in various subjects" or "on various subjects"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> They offer classes on various subjects.
>
> They offer classes in various subjects.

Which is correct?

Searching google for "classes in/on various subjects" shows that both variants are used frequently.

But after changing "subjects" to e.g. "chemistry",

> They offer classes on chemistry.
>
> They offer classes in chemistry.

1st variant sounds a bit wrong to me.
Is it not?

So what is the pattern here? Does "in" and "on" are equivalent here, or maybe be they have a slight difference in meaning, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

By and large, you should use whatever you would use if *various* weren't there. So

> He spoke **on** various subjects

And

> She has several degrees **in** various subjects

Not to mention

> There were participants **from** various countries.

However, usage throws up alternatives from time to time. Thus both of your examples are attested and most people see nothing strange about that.